Show that equi-bicolored tree has at least one leaf of each color
I need to solve the following problem using induction:
Every equi-bicolored tree has at least one leaf of each color.
Equi-bicolored means that a tree is 2-colored and has the same number of vertices of each color.
I did this proof already using the fact that if a partition does not have a leaf, it leads to a contradiction. Now I need to do it using induction but I'm stuck on how to "shrink" the tree to apply the induction

If you don't have to use induction, see this for a quick proof.

@CalvinLin thank you. I've done a proof very similar to that one. I need a different proof now

What is the context that you have to solve this via induction?

Just out of curiosity

If you want to use induction, you can't pull off 1 vertex at a time - you have to remove 2, since order of your equi-bi-coloured trees is even. So removing two leaves (two well chosen leaves?) may be a starting point for induction.

@BrandonduPreez I see. I can't understand how to do it, because when I can't guarantee that there are two leaves of different colors when going from a tree with n vertices to a tree with n - 2(or n+2 to n)

@BrandonduPreez removing two leaves doesn't work because you can't assume you have two leaves of different colors.
You have to use edge contraction to prove by induction
